# Data is not refreshing instantly while other person send message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing chat app in android and using firebase for it my chat activity's code is given below

```
public class Chat extends CustomActivity {

/**
 * The Conversation list.
 */
private ArrayList<Conversation> convList;

/**
 * The chat adapter.
 */
private ChatAdapter adp;

/**
 * The Editext to compose the message.
 */
private EditText txt;

/**
 * The user name of buddy.
 */
private ChatUser buddy;

/**
 * The date of last message in conversation.
 */
private Date lastMsgDate;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat);

    convList = new ArrayList<Conversation>();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adp = new ChatAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adp);
    list.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    list.setStackFromBottom(true);

    txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);

    setTouchNClick(R.id.btnSend);

    buddy = (ChatUser) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Const.EXTRA_DATA);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null)
        actionBar.setTitle(buddy.getUsername());

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").orderByChild("receiver").endAt(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null) {
                //convList=new ArrayList<Conversation>();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()  ) {
                    Conversation conversation = ds.getValue(Conversation.class);
                    if (conversation.getReceiver().contentEquals(user.getUid()) || conversation.getSender().contentEquals(user.getUid())) {
                        //     if(!convList.contains(conversation)) {
                        convList.add(conversation);
                        if (lastMsgDate == null
                                || lastMsgDate.before(conversation.getDate()))
                            lastMsgDate = conversation.getDate();

                        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    // }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onResume()
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadConversationList();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onPause()
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.socialshare.custom.CustomFragment#onClick(android.view.View)
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    super.onClick(v);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSend) {
        sendMessage();
    }

}

/**
 * Call this method to Send message to opponent. It does nothing if the text
 * is empty otherwise it creates a Parse object for Chat message and send it
 * to Parse server.
 */
private void sendMessage() {
    if (txt.length() == 0)
        return;

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txt.getWindowToken(), 0);

    String s = txt.getText().toString();




    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null) {
        final Conversation conversation = new Conversation(s,
                Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),
                user.getUid(),
                buddy.getId(),
                "");
        conversation.setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_SENDING);
        convList.add(conversation);
        final String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("messages")
                .push().getKey();

        //Experiment By Pratap
      /*  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if(user != null) {
                    Conversation conversation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conversation.class);
                    if (conversation.getReceiver().contentEquals(user.getUid()) || conversation.getSender().contentEquals(user.getUid())) {
                        convList.add(conversation);
                        if (lastMsgDate == null
                                || lastMsgDate.before(conversation.getDate()))
                            lastMsgDate = conversation.getDate();

                        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });*/
        //

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").child(key)
                .setValue(conversation)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                               if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                   convList.get(convList.indexOf(conversation)).setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_SENT);
                                               } else {
                                                   convList.get(convList.indexOf(conversation)).setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_FAILED);
                                               }
                                               FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                                       .getReference("messages")
                                                       .child(key).setValue(convList.get(convList.indexOf(conversation)))
                                                       .addOnCompleteListener(new
                                                                                      OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                                          @Override
                                                                                          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                                              adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                                                          }
                                                                                      });

                                           }
                                       }
                );
    }
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    txt.setText(null);
}

/**
 * Load the conversation list from Parse server and save the date of last
 * message that will be used to load only recent new messages
 */
private void loadConversationList() {

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Conversation conversation = ds.getValue(Conversation.class);
                    if (conversation.getReceiver().contentEquals(user.getUid()) || conversation.getSender().contentEquals(user.getUid())) {
                     //   if(!convList.contains(conversation)) {
                            convList.add(conversation);
                            if (lastMsgDate == null
                                    || lastMsgDate.before(conversation.getDate()))
                                lastMsgDate = conversation.getDate();

                            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                   // }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

/**
 * The Class ChatAdapter is the adapter class for Chat ListView. This
 * adapter shows the Sent or Receieved Chat message in each list item.
 */
private class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return convList.size();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Conversation getItem(int arg0) {
        return convList.get(arg0);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
        Conversation c = getItem(pos);
        if (c.isSent())
            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item_sent, null);
        else
            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item_rcv, null);

        TextView lbl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl1);
        lbl.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(Chat.this, c
                        .getDate().getTime(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS,
                DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, 0));

        lbl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl2);
        lbl.setText(c.getMsg());

        lbl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl3);
        if (c.isSent()) {
            if (c.getStatus() == Conversation.STATUS_SENT)
                lbl.setText(R.string.delivered_text);
            else {
                if (c.getStatus() == Conversation.STATUS_SENDING)
                    lbl.setText(R.string.sending_text);
                else {
                    lbl.setText(R.string.failed_text);
                }
            }
        } else
            lbl.setText("");

        return v;
    }

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I just want to load single message when user sends or receive message can any one help me in this and i am little weak in database design here is my json structure of database is there any mistake in database? or code please suggest me

```
{
    "messages": {
        "-KJNARNlP47TwU1tTPrd": {
            "date": {
                "date": 3,
                "day": 5,
                "hours": 17,
                "minutes": 31,
                "month": 5,
                "seconds": 45,
                "time": 1464989505080,
                "timezoneOffset": 240,
                "year": 116
            },
            "msg": "Hey Joe",
            "photoUrl": "",
            "receiver": "Uhph7zwnAyQnSqHnw0uWbHI6zpv1",
            "sender": "P4hJs5t9BaN6QsFYcGLRw6B5a7P2",
            "sent": false,
            "status": 1
        },
        "-KJNCItxjYmAh5XNTLGP": {
            "date": {
                "date": 3,
                "day": 5,
                "hours": 17,
                "minutes": 39,
                "month": 5,
                "seconds": 54,
                "time": 1464989994581,
                "timezoneOffset": 240,
                "year": 116
            },
            "msg": "How are you guys doing",
            "photoUrl": "",
            "receiver": "Uhph7zwnAyQnSqHnw0uWbHI6zpv1",
            "sender": "P4hJs5t9BaN6QsFYcGLRw6B5a7P2",
            "sent": true,
            "status": 1
        },
        "-KJNCYPfBfCI5PiqQ4ZX": {
            "date": {
                "date": 3,
                "day": 5,
                "hours": 17,
                "minutes": 40,
                "month": 5,
                "seconds": 58,
                "time": 1464990058115,
                "timezoneOffset": 240,
                "year": 116
            },
            "msg": "OK seems your busy catch you later",
            "photoUrl": "",
            "receiver": "Uhph7zwnAyQnSqHnw0uWbHI6zpv1",
            "sender": "P4hJs5t9BaN6QsFYcGLRw6B5a7P2",
            "sent": true,
            "status": 1
        },
        "-KJNDuBgl4eGHzz7jG_U": {
            "date": {
                "date": 3,
                "day": 5,
                "hours": 17,
                "minutes": 46,
                "month": 5,
                "seconds": 53,
                "time": 1464990413564,
                "timezoneOffset": 240,
                "year": 116
            },
            "msg": "Checking back in",
            "photoUrl": "",
            "receiver": "Uhph7zwnAyQnSqHnw0uWbHI6zpv1",
            "sender": "P4hJs5t9BaN6QsFYcGLRw6B5a7P2",
            "sent": true,
            "status": 1
        },
        "-KJNEDgwYsIX7I0EGWbM": {
            "date": {
                "date": 3,
                "day": 5,
                "hours": 17,
                "minutes": 48,
                "month": 5,
                "seconds": 17,
                "time": 1464990497565,
                "timezoneOffset": 240,
                "year": 116
            },
            "msg": "Apologies was away for a while",
            "photoUrl": "",
            "receiver": "P4hJs5t9BaN6QsFYcGLRw6B5a7P2",
            "sender": "Uhph7zwnAyQnSqHnw0uWbHI6zpv1",
            "sent": true,
            "status": 1
        },
        "-KNcnTK_pg_s2MOOZ8W1": {
            "date": {
                "date": 26,
                "day": 2,
                "hours": 16,
                "minutes": 3,
                "month": 6,
                "seconds": 19,
                "time": 1469563399536,
                "timezoneOffset": 240,
                "year": 116
            },
            "msg": "hey",
            "photoUrl": "",
            "receiver": "Uhph7zwnAyQnSqHnw0uWbHI6zpv1",
            "sender": "P4hJs5t9BaN6QsFYcGLRw6B5a7P2",
            "sent": true,
            "status": 1
        }
    },
    "users": {
        "P4hJs5t9BaN6QsFYcGLRw6B5a7P2": {
            "email": "demo@myapptemplates.com",
            "id": "P4hJs5t9BaN6QsFYcGLRw6B5a7P2",
            "online": true,
            "room": ["home"],
            "username": "Joe Soap"
        },
        "Uhph7zwnAyQnSqHnw0uWbHI6zpv1": {
            "email": "demo1@myapptemplates.com",
            "id": "Uhph7zwnAyQnSqHnw0uWbHI6zpv1",
            "online": true,
            "room": ["home"],
            "username": "Busy Bee"
        }
    }
```

Comment: how much times it's taking to reflect?

Comment: right now i have only two users so it is not taking to much time but i am afraid when users increases it will take lot more time so i want my database and code perfect can you please help me

Comment: I also don't know much about database.

Comment: ok bro i am trying very hard on this reffered lots of tutorials and source codes but none of them are useful to me

Comment: Instead of ValueEventListener you have to use ChildEventListener because  ValueEventListener  load all data again when you get single new message but ChildEventListener load only new message. so it's save your network fetch time

Comment: bro it is loading chat tadat multiple time in app can you suggest solution?

Comment: onChildAdded is get call for each message for first time. So when this method get called you have to take message from that method and put in ArrayList and call adapter.notifyItemInserted(int position) method for refreshing the view